# Creating pod from Unity iOS project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I have created a game with Unity.

I have exported it as a Xcode project.

I want to create a pod from that Xcode project.

My problem is that the exported Unity project has a `Native` folder that contains way too many files.

When installing my podspec for the Unity project my computer runs out of ram when trying to write up the `Pods.xcodeproj`.

Has anyone faced a similar problem as this one?

Answer (score 1):

No you can perfectly do that. But in order to achieve what you are asking, you should your game as a view in native ios and then use cocoapods to add extra capabilities to your ios app. In this case your game becomes like a component in your native ios app and you can play with the rest of your app as you wish here is a guide that can help you;

https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not do that. Unity creates a XCode project that is not supposed to be versioned or reused in any way. It is just necessary to create a working iOS version of your game and sometimes used for debug proposes but it is an ephemeral thing. If you want to redistribute your game you should do it using the Unity project itself.